# How to get selected value from drop down list in VueJs?

Tags: vue.js

I have one textbox and one dropdownlist here. The dropdownlist list and textbox event works. My problem is how do I get the selected value of the dropdownlist on keyup event? I have google it. It looks different from vanilla javascript approach. I tried to add v-model in the select tag but once I have added it, the dropdownlist no longer works.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      currency_from_amount: 0,
      currencyFromOptions: [],
      selected: ''
    };
  },
  methods: {
    convert: function(event) {
      debugger

    }
  },
  mounted() {
    axios
      .get("https://openexchangerates.org/api/currencies.json")
      .then(response => (this.currencyFromOptions = response.data))
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        
      })
      .finally(() => (this.loading = false));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input class="form-control" type="number" name="currency_from_amount" id="currency_from_amount" v-model="currency_from_amount" @keyup="convert">

  <select class="form-control" name="currency_from_code" id="currency_from_code">
    <option v-for="(value,key) in currencyFromOptions" :value="key">{{ value }}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Add v-model to select and use that value

Comment: what do you mean *ch. I tried to add v-model in the select tag but once I have added it, the dropdownlist no longer works* ?

Comment: The dropdownlist for first option is empty. And when I console.log(selected), it the empty

Comment: but when i print `this.selected` inside the `convert` method i can see its value , i already have bound selected to select

Comment: it's okay. I solved it already. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the selected variable, add a change handler as below

```
<select class="form-control" name="currency_from_code" id="currency_from_code" @change="onSelected($event)">
```

Write a method as below

```
onSelected:function(event){
          this.selected = event.target.value;
        }
```

Once you set this variable,you can use the same in keyup event

Comment: It works but only for dropdownlist onchange event. But, for textbox keyup event, `event.target.value` become textbox value instead of dropdownlist selected value.

Comment: @Steve inside the text box keyup event you must use this variable this.selected instead of event.target.value to make use of dropdown list's value